# Why do I need to call a function explicitly rather than passing it in as a callback to pass my test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner, sinon

Test:

```
it('call:start', function () {
  rootScope.$broadcast('call:start');
  expect(controller.conditionalPause.called).to.equal(true);
});
```

Passes:

```
$rootScope.$on('call:start', function () {
  self.conditionalPause();
});
```

Fails:

```
$rootScope.$on('call:start', self.conditionalPause);
```

Why?

In the failing test, it hits `$on 'call:start` and calls the callback. It even logs something out when I add a `console.log` to `self.conditionalPause`. So why isn't the test passing?

Comment: `self.conditionalPause.bind(self)`

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. Do you mind writing up the explanation as an answer? Also, any idea why I'm getting `undefined is not a function`, referring to `bind` when I run my Karma test? Is it overriding `Function.bind` or something?

Comment: It has to do with how `this` works. There are probably a bunch of duplicates for this particular case, but here is the most complete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: I happen to know, but I figured it'd be useful to others who come across the question. It isn't immediately obvious that this is a `this` issue. At least not to me. I didn't find any dupes in searching, but maybe my queries were bad.

Comment: Regarding the bind issue with Karma, if you are using PhantomJS make sure it is at least version 2, otherwise you may have to include a polyfill.

Comment: I found another [detailed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback), hope that helps. The key is understanding that `function(){return f()} === f` and `function(){return a.f()} === function(){return a.f.call(a)} === a.f.bind(a)`